# translation for word "month", "day" and "year" using date-fn

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'm trying to use date-fns (https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns) to retrieve the translations for the word "month", "day" and "year". I don't want the translations for the name of the months, I want the translations for the word itself "month".

Is this possible? Or does this package not provide it?

Answer (score 0):

Look into this:
https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/locale/en-US/_lib/formatDistance/index.ts#L43

And into https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/docs/i18nContributionGuide.md for information how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up discovering and using the built in Intl API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl